# Excel - Accessing file, exclamation point (!) in subfolder

Tags: vba, excel

I was asked to help a user who's excel file references another file but is failing.  Looking into the issue, they have an exclamation point in a subfolder  At this point they are unable to rename the folder or move the file.

Open to suggestions

These examples work

='C:\temp2\excelTest\[GoodFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1

='C:\temp2\excelTest\[Bad!File.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1

This fails

='C:\temp2\excelTest\bad!Folder\[GoodFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1

I've attempted to open the file using VBA but had similar results.

```
Public Sub testVBA()
Dim FileName As String

Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

'Works
FileName = "C:\temp2\excelTest\GoodFile.xlsx"

'Fails
'FileName = "C:\temp2\excelTest\Bad!Folder\GoodFile.xlsx"
' escaping the ! also fails
'FileName = "C:\temp2\excelTest\Bad" & Chr(34) & "Folder\GoodFile.xlsx"
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1")

MsgBox (wsTarget.Range("A1"))
```

End Sub

Comment: Are you missing a slash in the path?  `='C:\temp2\excelTest\bad!Folder\[GoodFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1`

Comment: I tested this with a folder that had an exclamation point in it and there wasn't an issue. I dont think the exclamation point is the issue. Also, regarding your attempt at using `Chr(34)` to escape the character, that code is for a quote `"` not for an exclamation point `!`. For exclamation, you need `Chr(33)`. https://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php

Comment: Thanks for catching that BruceWayne - I had the slash in the original text but following it with the bracket must have tried to escape it so S.O. just showed [ instead of \ [    I've fixed the post.

Comment: Brandon - Thanks for catching the incorrect ASCII code.  Ignoring that flub, I reran the tests and it worked - both inside the cell and using VBA.  I also went back to an email I sent the user with a version of the path that was failing before and it now works.

You are right, the ! doesn't appear to be the issue.  Seeing as everything is local and the only change is I've opened and closed Excel a few times since this morning, I'm a little stumped as to the root cause. Could be I typo'ed something else.